# platformwebservice not used anymore after I have implemented custom webservice

Tags: web-services, customization, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to custom some DTO and Ressources from platformwebservices, so I follow the Hybris instruction to create a custom extension for WEB Services.

You can mark one of your own extensions as a webservice extension:

```
1 - Create a new extension using the yempty template.
2 - Add the new extension to localextensions.xml file.
3 - In the command line go to the platform directory and call: ant.
4 - In the command line go to the new extension directory and call ant webservice_nature -Dextname=customextension.

Running this task gives the selected extension a nature of platformwebservices extension. It results in:

1 - Generation of a new web.xml file. If one already exists, it is renamed to web.xml.old.
2 - Generation of the extension_name -web-spring.xml located in extension_name /resources directory, unless it already exists there.
3 - An additional entry in the Platform's local.properties file, 

file : local.properties

webservice.module={extensionname}
```

I can compile (ant clean all) and launch the server but when I try do execute a request in postman like : https://localhost:9002/ws410/rest/products/
it's not working, it gives me a 404 error.

if I remove my customExtension in local extension.xml and "webservice.module={extensionname}" in local.properties 
and execute the request (same url) It's give a 200 with the correct response.

The fact is, when my customExtension is set the platformwebservices is not used anymore.

Comment: how did you configure the webroots of the extensions?

Comment: When I read the documentation, it's says, we have to set the webroot of our custom extension in the local.properties : ${extensionname}.weebroot=/${path},             the only reference I have about webroot, it's :                                                                                              <webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/ws410"/> : define in mycustomextension.extensioninfo.xml

Comment: Is there another extension with that webroot?